# Write pdf files with phpexcel bundle?

Tags: symfony

How to print a pdf file with phpExcel Bundle.. the documentation show how to write a xls file with the code:

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=stdream2.xls');
```

This is working, but i don't have idea how to write a pdf file?

Any suggestion?

Comment: The address for download the phpexcel bundle is..http://knpbundles.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle

Comment: use 'application/vnd.ms-excel' and not 'text/vnd.ms-excel', which does not exist.
( full list of mimetypes: https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml#L1898 )

Answer (score 1):

The new version of https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle 
now has pdf and xlsx support.